# When not to split up the VO verb?

Tags: grammar

```
虽然是坑爹了，但是认错态度很好。
(He got his father in trouble, but it's good for him to admit his bad attitude.)
```

I see the verb 认错 a VO verb(verb-object).

So shouldn't it be something like this as follow?

```
虽然是坑爹了，但是认他的态度的错很好。（认 Object(his bad attitude) 错）
```

I gave my Chinese friend this sentence with the verb separated, but she said that sounds a  little weird.

I'd like to know what I am missing here.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: 1. '认他的态度的错', not *a little* weird, but *very* weird -- though comprehensible and indeed grammatically correct. I think the problem is most Chinese even don't realize 认错 is a VO verb. I treat this kind of usage as "language intuition", and I'd like to see if anyone can provide a grammatical explanation. 2. '坑爹', recently it becomes an Internet slang, meaning "entrapping me". Probably the translation "got his father in trouble" is wrong.

Comment: @Stan Thanks. I appreciate you for the great explanation of 坑爹

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I think that the sentence should be:

```
虽然是坑爹了，但是认错态度很好。
(He made some mistake, but he had good attitude for admitting his mistake.)
```

坑爹 means did something wrong, it's none of his father's business,or you can say 他做了不靠谱的事，但是认错态度很好。

Second, 认错态度 means has a good attitude for admitting one's mistake.

Such as:

```
对于历史，日本没有好的认错态度。
（For history, Japan do not has a good attitude for admitting its mistake ）
```

Comment: 答案为什么给扣分了，why was the answer marked down？

Comment: 可能我只给出解释，没有分析语法.

Answer (score 2):

（Taking for granted that VO－verb means the same as 离合词。） Putting any object as attributive in between the ２ characters （把宾语插在离合词两字中间充当定语）is not the only way of dealing with objects，probably not even the most common way。Some typical examples of object as attributive in between：

婆婆住了四个多月的院。 今天我跑了两个小时的步。这对中年夫妻是去年复的昏。那伙匪徒又绑了谁的架。The attributive in-between case includes attributive w/o 的：你妈给我留了什么话没有？

this method may not be available， except for very simple attributives like 什么，例句：他认什么错 (see 他认了什么罪？ below)

aThe other more common way seems to be fronting object with a preposition as adverbial adjunct （用介词把宾语提到前面充当状语，这些介词包括“和、给、为、向、跟”等）e.g.他们很有礼貌地向我们行礼。可以请你为我们照一张相吗？

６ of preceding examples are from http://forum.swissinfo.ch/viewtopic.php?f=73&t=36685

＂现代汉语离合词用法词典＂does not include ＂认错＂ but has ＂认真＂ and ＂认罪＂：Examples of 离用法 （excluding well known 了，过，着 in between， only last 例句 may be relevant）

认真：＂认＂后带补语：人家开玩笑的，你怎么就认起真来
了？

认罪：＂认＂后带补语：他就没认过一次罪。
＂罪＂提到＂认＂前：他连罪都不认，怎么能说他态度好。
＂罪＂前带定语：他认了什么罪？

Comment: in fact 他认什么错 does not seem to exist either although 他认了什么罪？ does exist (错 being considered an adjective in this case?)